# The group options for a date, time or date-time condition field must be a date group

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using VS2017 and trying to convert my reports from Delphi to Asp.Net, but the problem with some until this point that My users can change their sort from the GUI and I need to dynamically adjust the sort in code to match their selection.

To do this I use the following code:

`ReportDocument.DataDefinition.Groups[i].ConditionField = ReportDocument.Database.Tables[CrystalReportDatasource].Fields[cField];`

However if `cField` is a`DateField` and the original is a `StringField` group I receive the following exception:

```
The group options for a date, time or date-time condition field must be a date 
group options object crystal reports" when I try and excute the above 
statement.
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

When you group on a date, Crystal needs to know what type of date grouping you wish to apply (e.g. Every Day, week, or Month...).
You need to take care of that aspect in code or simply create a String formula to convert the date column to a string and Group on that formula instead of on the raw date column.

Comment: Thanks for replay, however can you please provide more details how to implement this approach. @MilletSoftware